# Why does 'toSet' method mix up ordering of elements in ListBuffer?

Tags: scala, collections, set, listbuffer

In scala, why does `toSet()` method mix up the order of elements in a collection (`ListBuffer`)?

Which collection can I use to both secure uniqueness of each element and keep their original order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the [set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html) abstraction, being a subclass of the [traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Traversable.html), has no guarantees about the order of elements held within:

```
A traversable class might or might not have two properties: strictness and orderedness. Neither is represented as a type.
 ...
 If the class is not ordered, foreach can visit elements in different orders for different runs (but it will keep the same order in the same run).'
```

More precisely about why the elements get 'mangled': the `toSet` method constructs a new set collection out of some existing collection. It uses the default set implementation for this new set collection. The default set implementation is based on a hash table. In a hash table, the order of elements is undefined.

Comment: There is the `mutable.LinkedHashSet` collection if you need element uniqueness. The elements within it are traversed in the order in which they were added.